# MTM 2017 Supports Coded UI test execution with vNext build

Tags: tfs, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, vnext

We were using MTM 2015 and TFS 2015. While trying to run the Coded UI automation with vNext build started encountering an issue

> The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access
>   permission is required

Started digging deep and then came across this link [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#RunTest).

At the end if you see Q and A:

> **Q: Can I use vNext builds to run automated tests in lab environments?**
>
> A: Currently only XAML builds are supported with automated testing.
>   **Microsoft Test Manager does not support Team Foundation 2015 build
>   (also called Build vNext).** Microsoft Test Manager will allow you to
>   associate a vNext build with your Test Plan, but when you try to
>   trigger an automated test using a lab environment, your test run will
>   fail and the error log will show you the following message - which may
>   be misleading.
>
> **The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required**

Question is does MTM 2017 supports Coded UI automation execution with vNext build? If not when can we expect this MTM + vNext build work without any issues?

Answer (score 1):

No. That feature will not be added to MTM; MTM and [Lab Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/09/04/how-to-perform-lab-management-operations-in-build-and-release/) are deprecated in favor of the full web-based test hub experience. When you run MTM 2017, it even pops up a warning telling you this. It's also worth noting that Coded UI is deprecated in favor of Selenium for web browser-based testing and Appium for desktop testing. Although all of these tools are still supported, they are no longer receiving feature updates.

You can [run test automation from release definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=vsts) in TFS 2017 and 2018.

Comment: Does this mean, if we have Win Form apps and invested in coded UI, we need to use MTM 2013 and TFS 2015 with Xaml builds and no chance to upgrade to higher versions?

Comment: @SubrahmanyamChilakamarthi All of the existing stuff will continue to work, but may not be compatible with newer features. You can run your Coded UI tests from TFS 2017 or 2018, but not from MTM -- there is a new way of doing it that removes the need for MTM.

Comment: "You can run your Coded UI tests from TFS 2017 or 2018, but not from MTM -- there is a new way of doing it that removes the need for MTM" -  

Can you point me to a video or document where this is explained?

Comment: @SubrahmanyamChilakamarthi Look at the last link in my answer, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=vsts